# Python - removing double quotation marks " so that script runs

Tags: python, arcmap

I am using Python scripts to edit the table of many shape files.  The following script runs fine, but if there are any " marks in the SIT_FULL_S field, the script errors and shuts down.

```
gp.CalculateField_management(fc + "\\Parcels.shp","SIT_FULL_S", "!SIT_FULL_S!.lstrip('0')", "PYTHON")
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Error running expression: "9030 W SR 2 HWY "A"".lstrip('0') <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

I have two options, create a new script that runs through and deletes all occurances of ", and then run the above script or modify the above script to ignore the " and contiue running.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 3):

Escape it:

```
"string \"inner string\""
```

or don't mix quotations:

```
'string "inner string"'
```

Comment: Or triple-quote it: `"""'string', "other string", etc."""`

Comment: I tried the suggestion below to escape it, but got the following error:

gp.CalculateField_management(fc + "\\Parcels.shp","SIT_FULL_S", "!SIT_FULL_S !.lstrip('0\""\"')", "PYTHON") ^ SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character –

Comment: I found this, but am having issues using it.